# How to match a fan curve in Openmodelica buildings SpeedControlled_y pump or fan

Tags: openmodelica

Trying to optimize some ducting configuration I want to model a system of ducts with a fan to simulate the flow and pressure distribution.
In order to choose the right fan I want to add a fan curve from the fan supplier. But how to get the fan to behave like the curve says it should?

Using a SpeedControlled_y pump from the Buildings library I want to match this performance curve:

[image]

The test setup was adapted from Buildings.Fluid.Movers.Examples.ClosedLoop_y
[image]
I tried testing this by adding a pressure drop (called inlet in the immage) and changing it from very large to very low. (inlet_nominal in the code below)
But what ever I do I never get points on the curve. Especially for low pressure drops I get values for flow that exceed 110m3/h (or 0.0235kg/s as calculated). For example when I set inlet_nominal = 20 Pa. The simulation gives a flow of 0.0258kg/s (*4680 = 120m3/h) and a pressure over the fan (fan.dp) of 29Pa. I would expect either a smaller pressure with that flow or a smaller flow with that pressure.

The values for the pressure curve are in the table below. kg/s is calculated with a density of 1.3 kg/m3

|  | m3/h | kg/s | Pa |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 0 | 175 |
| * | 10 | 0.00214 | 170 |
| * | 70 | 0.0150 | 100 |
| * | 105 | 0.0224 | 20 |
|  | 110 | 0.02354 | 0 |

The values marked * are in the per definition in the code example below where the fan curve is defined. (per(pressure(V_flow = {0.0002, 0.015, 0.0224},dp = {170, 100, 20})))
 The other values I tries earlier. The results are similar.

```
model FanTest01
  package Medium = Buildings.Media.Air;
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate m_flow_nominal = 0.0224 "Nominal mass flow rate";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.MassFlowRate m_flow_nominal_fan = 0.0128 "110m3/h Nominal mass flow rate for fan";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.PressureDifference dp_nominal = 5 "Nominal pressure difference";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.PressureDifference dp_nominal_fan = 117 "Nominal pressure difference for fan";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.PressureDifference inlet_nominal = 20 "Inlet pressure difference";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length steek = 0.44 "Horizontale steek tussen modulles";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Length diameter = 0.08 "Buis diameter";
  // FAN
  Buildings.Fluid.Movers.SpeedControlled_y fan(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
  per(pressure(V_flow = {0.0002, 0.015, 0.0224},
    dp = {170, 100, 20})), 
    energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial) "Fan" annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {70, 30}, extent = {{40, 40}, {60, 60}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Buildings.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT sou(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T = 293.15, nPorts = 2, p = 101300, use_p_in = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {82, 0}, extent = {{-82, 10}, {-62, 30}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Buildings.Fluid.FixedResistances.HydraulicDiameter duct01(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    dh = diameter, fac = 1, length = 0.44,
    m_flow_nominal = m_flow_nominal) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {150, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Buildings.Fluid.FixedResistances.HydraulicDiameter duct02(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    dh = diameter, fac = 1, length = 0.44,
    m_flow_nominal = m_flow_nominal) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 80}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Buildings.Fluid.FixedResistances.PressureDrop inlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    dp_nominal = inlet_nominal,
    m_flow_nominal = m_flow_nominal) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {50, 50}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp ramp(duration = 100, startTime = 10) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 110}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(fan.port_b, duct01.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{130, 80}, {140, 80}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(duct01.port_b, sou.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{160, 80}, {170, 80}, {170, 20}, {20, 20}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(ramp.y, fan.y) annotation(
    Line(points = {{101, 110}, {120, 110}, {120, 92}}, color = {0, 0, 127}));
  connect(fan.port_a, duct02.port_b) annotation(
    Line(points = {{110, 80}, {100, 80}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(inlet.port_a, sou.ports[2]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, 40}, {50, 20}, {20, 20}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(inlet.port_b, duct02.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{50, 60}, {50, 80}, {80, 80}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio = true, extent = {{-200, 160}, {200, -240}})),
    Documentation(info = "<html>
<p>
Adapted from 'ClosedLoop_y' example.
</p>
</html>"),
    __Dymola_Commands(file = "modelica://Buildings/Resources/Scripts/Dymola/Fluid/Movers/Examples/ClosedLoop_y.mos" "Simulate and plot"),
    experiment(StopTime = 200, Tolerance = 1e-06, StartTime = 0, Interval = 1),
    uses(Buildings(version = "9.1.0"), Modelica(version = "4.0.0")),
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-200, -260}, {200, 160}}, preserveAspectRatio = true)),
    version = "");
end FanTest01;
```

What should I change to get simulation results closer to the desired fan curve from the supplier? It could well be I'm doing something silly wrong.

Comment: I had a [similar question](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings/discussions/3362) related to the parameterization of the pump model in the MBL. Consider posting your question also to [GitHub Discussions](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings/discussions) if you have not yet solved your problem.

Comment: I am posting here the link to the discussion on [GitHub](https://github.com/lbl-srg/modelica-buildings/discussions/3370) as a reference in case other users face similar problems.